# Script que Salve a página e mude a URL, e Salve a próxima página

Tags: php, javascript, html, python, .net

Bom, estou com um problema que ao meu ver é simples, porém na prática é complexo, estou precisando de um Script na qual ele Salve diversas páginas URL e mude para a próxima URL, Exemplo:

www.exemplo.com/1
Salvo 1 
Next > www.exemplo.com/2
Salvo 2
Next > www.exemplo.com/3
Salvo 3

O problema é que eu não tenho muito conhecimento em Javascript, PHP e nem HTML, tenho um entendimento básico sobre o Python, só que ainda não é possivel realizar essa ação.

Praticamente preciso de um Auto-Save-As, porém que ele mude de URL e Salve novamente, pois são mais de 17.627 Páginas, e Humanamente isso é ímpossivel.

Só que só tem como rodar isso no meu computador, Sites externos não conseguem acha-ló, pois o site tem Login.

Se possivel conseguirem algum Script que consiga realizar isso, eu agradeço.

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que o método [PushState()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/History_API#Exemplo_do_m%C3%A9todo_pushState()) possa ajudar.